# No height on grid rows with absolute children

Tags: css, flexbox

I've built a flexbox grid layout with multiple rows, but since these rows' children are absolutely positioned, the rows don't accumulate any height and so they overlap each other.

I can think of a few hacky workarounds, but I'm not sure what the best solution for this is.

Relevant CSS:

```
.events-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
}

.card {
  flex-basis: 31.3%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.card .card-flip-cont {
  padding: 15px;
}

.card .card-flip-cont .card-front,
.card .card-flip-cont .card-back {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/oBeXzq

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute;` takes the element out of the flow, there's no way to have the parent extend down to the absolute children's height automatically. You need to explicitly set some height on the cards.

If you have a proportion you want for the cards, I'd suggest to use `padding-bottom: XX%;` on the `.card` class, but you have to have some strategy in case the content in the cards is longer than the height you specified. `padding-bottom` with a % value uses the `width` of the parent (your row) as the base value.